# Multiple services or single service with multiple threads

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, architecture, windows-services

We are rewriting our .net application. Current application has 4 windows services. First service accepts requests from the UI and also updates the UI by publishing events for refreshing UI. This service internally uses 2 thrall pools with Max 16 threads each to service GUI. Any requests from UI that requires business processing is passed on to the worker process windows services(there are 2 such windows service).MSMQ is used for passing the requests back and forth between services. Fourth windows service acts like a load balancing and directs requests from first service to the workers. All services are running on the same box

Now while rewriting, we would like to know if we should maintain the same architecture or can it be all clubbed into same service with separate threads. Which will be better from performance perspective.

Answer (score 6):

For now you are running it on same box, but do you think you may require to scale to multiple boxes in future?

The architecture involving multiple services is more scalable, more maintainable and more flexible. Some of the key benefits you get are,

- Your architecture is more loosely coupled
- You can scale each service / workload separately
- You can replace each service in a different technology
  (maybe someday you would like to implement your worker process using
  C++ on Linux), you have flexibility to do that
- Its easier to add new features to your system, for example if you
  want to add additional logging, you can just hook to MSMQ and start
  logging your messages without touching your actual code

Multi-threading may give you a bit of performance boost due to reduced latency, but if you are running both systems on same machine, then there won't be much difference. But if you every get into trouble due to high-load and you want to scale your business logic service only; then you will be out of luck. So I would always go with multi-services (kind of micro-service architecture) that gives separation of concerns and other benefits.

I hope this helps.